# ¿Cómo consultar un solo dato de los dos asignados?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Espero poder darme a entender por el título, pero si no, Pues tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la cual debo de hacer la consulta de listar los perros que no han sido vacunados contra la rabia. Como pueden observar en la siguiente tabla, en total hay 10 perros con nombre diferente y que tienen varias vacunas. Algunos tienen la del Parvovirus (Identificada como 1) o la de la Rabia (Identificada como 2) o ambas.
El caso es que he tratado de realizar la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  consulta2.NOMBRE_MASCOTA, consulta2.COD_VACUNA
FROM
(SELECT dueños.mascota AS NOMBRE_MASCOTA, vacuna.vacuna AS NOMBRE_VACUNA, vacuna.idVacuna AS COD_VACUNA
FROM vacunacion,dueños,vacuna
WHERE vacunacion.idDueño = dueños.idDueño AND vacunacion.idVacuna = vacuna.idVacuna) AS consulta2
HAVING consulta2.COD_VACUNA = 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar esta consulta me muestra los siguientes resultados estos resultados, pero deberian de ser unicamente 4 perros los cuales me deberian de salir en vez de los 8, ya que los otros 4 cuentan con tanto la vacuna 1 y vacuna 2.
Entonces en sí, lo que necesito es solo conseguir que se muestren los perros que solo tengan la vacuna 1, no ambas.
¿No se si alguien pueda decirme sobre alguna instrucción que pueda emplear para obtener la consulta que deseo?

Comment: Aunque es perfectamente válido, por favor no unas las tablas con comas. Utiliza la sentencia `INNER JOIN`, que funciona exactamente igual, pero es más claro y legible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select mascota    
from tabla
where vacuna = 'Parvovirus'
and mascota not in
(
 select mascota 
 from tabla
 where vacuna = 'Rabia'
)
```

Aquí se hace una consulta principal que va a seleccionar todas las mascotas vacunadas contra el Parvovirus y usando el **operador not in** se verá cuales de estas mascotas de la consulta principal no han sido seleccionadas en la subconsulta. Esta subconsulta devuelve toda las mascotas vacunadas contra la rabia, por tanto como resultado final obtendremos todas las mascotas que han sido vacunadas contra el Parvovirus pero no contra la Rabia.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.
Con lo que me compartiste, pude dar solución a mi problema.
Saludos.